# Запретить увеличение блока в таблице в зависимости от контента с высотой 100%

Tags: html, css

Вся проблема описана в заголовке вопроса.

```html
<!--Есть документ, в котором таблица на вcю его высоту-->
<body style="background-color: #ff0; margin: 0;padding: 0;">
    <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; margin: 0;padding: 0;">
        <tr>
            <td>
        <!--В этой таблице блок, который на вcю её высоту. -->
        <!--Т.е. 100%. Это важно. Не подоёдёт что-то типа "измени на 100vh и т.п."-->
        <!--Т.к. таблица состоит ещё и из других строк.-->
                <div style="height: 100%; background-color: #f0f;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
 </table>
</body>
```

Всё работает так, как нужно. До тех пор, пока в этот блок не добавить что-то типа

```
1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
```

После этого таблица растягивается с контентом, тем самым у страницы появляется скроллбар. Это конечно замечательно, только мне этого не нужно. Мне нужно чтобы тот самый скроллбар появлялся у блока.

Если этому блоку добавить  `overflow: scroll;` то ничего хорошего не произойдёт.

Поведение становится нужным, если блоку добавить `overflow: auto;` Но это работает только для хрома.

Comment: почему только для хрома, для файерфокса тоже работает, думаю что эйдж тоже бутет пахать.

Answer (score 0):

Что-бы скролился определенный блок который нужен, а в body убрать скрол, надо body задать  overflow: hidden; а тому самому блоку задать  overflow: scroll;

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ff0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: scroll
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br> 1
        <br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br> 1
        <br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```